# Rollover buttons/images not aligned with links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, alignment, rollover

I have a temporary coming soon page up while I am working on my site, I added another social media button (email button) to the page and now the links are not aligned and are doubled up on each other. I have tried to figure out how to fix it but cannot seem to figure out what it missing. Any help would be appreciated

Below is the CSS & HTML:

```
ul.social
{
width: 350px;
margin: 80px auto 0;
height: 62px;
}

ul.social li{
float: left;
background: url(../images/social.png) left top no-repeat;
position: relative;
height: 62px;
margin-right: 28px;
}

ul.social li a{
display: block;
width: 62px;
height: 62px;
}


ul.social li.facebook{
height: 62px;
background-position: 0 0;
width: 62px;
}

ul.social li.facebook:hover{
background-position: 0 -62px;
}



ul.social li.pinterest{
height: 62px;
background-position: -90px 0;
width: 62px;
}

ul.social li.pinterest:hover{
background-position: -90px -62px;
}



ul.social li.linkedin{
height: 62px;
background-position: -180px 0;
width: 62px;
}

ul.social li.linkedin:hover{
background-position: -180px -62px;
}

ul.social li.email{
margin-right: 0;
height: 62px;
background-position: -270px 0;
width: 62px;
}

ul.social li.email:hover{
background-position: -270px -62px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div>
  <ul class="social">
   <li class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/heatherhannaydesigns"></li>
   <li class="pinterest"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/heatherlindsey6/"></li>
   <li class="linkedin"><a href="www.linkedin.com/pub/heather-hannay/7b/33b/56b/en"></li>
   <li class="email"><a href="mailto:info@heatherhannay.com"></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML has invalid markup. Don't know if that was unintentional or not, but the anchor tags `<a>` are not closed, `<a href="">...</a>`. Clean that up along with a visual of what the layout you're trying to achieve looks like vs what you're currently getting.

Comment: Thank you! yeah completely unintentional and definitely missed it!

Answer (score 0):

try closing your anchor tags

and adding list-style: none; padding: 0; to class ul.social first and recheck.